# I can't get a macro written in outlook to activate whenever I click the send button

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to write a macro with Microsoft Visual Basic in Outlook, but I can't get it to work when the send button is pressed. (To be more specific, I would like to check for attachments whenever the word "attach" is used.)

I have written the code to check for attachments but as I'm having difficulties with the trigger event, I'm testing with simpler code using just a MsgBox.

The code I'm using is this (in `ThisOutlookSession` -> `Application` -> `ItemSend`):

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

MsgBox "Try msgbox"

End Sub
```

Also, when there is a trigger event how do I partially execute my code to check for its correctness?

Comment: If your first VBA code see Trust Center https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-my-options-and-settings-in-the-Trust-Center-d672876e-20d3-4ad3-a178-343d044e05c8

Comment: You get one question per post. Your second question is a duplicate.

Comment: are you saying that the simpler code, that you have posted, does not work?

Comment: code will stop executing at command "stop".  so insert the command keyword "stop", on its own line, into your code. from there you can examine variable values and object properties, press F8 to single-step, or press F5 to continue.

Comment: Thank you for the trust center link, that was the problem. - Btw sorry if I put two questions in one, I'll be more careful.

Comment: @LisaDeeb  It is to your benefit to ask one question. You do not distract from the real question. As well, for the benefit of the community, if two users answer separate parts you cannot accept both answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small subroutine to test your event handler for all currently selected mails.

```
Private Sub MyTest()
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim Cancel As Boolean

    Cancel = False

    For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If TypeName(objItem) = "MailItem" Then                
            Call Application_ItemSend(item, Cancel)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Unlike subroutines with a non-empty list of parameters, this routine is listed as macro when you hit the `start` button. Therefore, you can step it through using the `VBA Debugger`.